# How to add an ImageIcon to an object?

Tags: java, oop, object, imageicon

I have the object 'Team' with some score variables, the name (String) and a logo. The logo has the type ImageIcon:

```
public class Team {

    public String name;
    public ImageIcon logo;
    public int points;
    public int plusGoals;
    public int minGoals;
    public int goalsTotal;


public Team (String name, ImageIcon logo, int points, int plusGoals, int minGoals, int goalsTotal){      

    this.name = name;
    this.logo = logo;
    this.points = points;
    this.plusGoals = plusGoals;
    this.minGoals = minGoals;
    goalsTotal = plusGoals - minGoals;
```

When I want to create a new object, and I enter the values of the object properties, I don't know how I can add the ImageIcon path.

So:

```
Team Blabla = new Team("Blabla", ..., 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I tried this things, but they doens't work:

```
Team Blabla = new Team("Blabla", C:\\Users\\path.png, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Team Blabla = new Team("Blabla", "C:\\Users\\path.png", 0, 0, 0, 0);
Team Blabla = new Team("Blabla", ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\path.png"), 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

How can I directly add an image path in this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can make a modification like:**

```
public Team(String name, String location, int points, int plusGoals,
            int minGoals, int goalsTotal) {
        this.logo = new ImageIcon(location); // using ImageIcon(URL location)    
         }
```

> **Note:** Here we are **using ImagIcon class** Constructor ->
>   **ImageIcon(URL location)** which Creates an ImageIcon from the specified URL.

**Working code**

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

class Team {

    public String name;
    public ImageIcon logo;
    public int points;
    public int plusGoals;
    public int minGoals;
    public int goalsTotal;

    public Team(String name, String location, int points, int plusGoals,
            int minGoals, int goalsTotal) {
        this.logo = new ImageIcon(location); // using ImageIcon(URL location)

        this.name = name;

        this.points = points;
        this.plusGoals = plusGoals;
        this.minGoals = minGoals;
        goalsTotal = plusGoals - minGoals;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("\n" + name + "\n" + logo + "\n" + points + "\n"
                + plusGoals + "\n" + minGoals + "\n" + goalsTotal);

    }
}

public class imageicon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Team obj = new Team("a", "C:\\Users\\path.png", 1, 2, 3, 4);
        obj.print();

    }
}
```